# About page blurb

Tags: discussion

Recently the about pages of the sites got updated.

[*Here is ours*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/about)

The thing is, we can edit the blurb at the top.

I open the floor to our users; What do we want people to know about us in a quick blurb?

Comment: It looks pretty awesome!

Answer (score 6):

"Movies and TV is a question and answer site for enthusiastic movie and tv viewers. We're the next best thing to a bag of popcorn."

The second sentence is me being silly, but I'd rather have the first sentence clearly explain that this site for those that are enthusiastic in the viewing of such things, not trying to create them.  That's what [AVP](https://video.stackexchange.com/) is for.

Answer (score 3):

Please capitalize television when it's abbreviated to "TV."